# combinations and proability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 120 books on 24 topics with 5 volumes on each topic.

What is the probability of choosing 3 books such that they all belong to different topics?

What is the probability of choosing "r" books such that at least one book is on a repeated topic?

Comment: For the first probability of choosing 3 books such that they are all of different topics:

The sample space is 120C3

The number of ways of choosing 3 books such that they are all of different topics is:
(120C1 * (120-5)C1 * (120-5*2)C1 / 3!)

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the probability of choosing 3 books such that they all belong to different topics?**

As you wrote in your comment, there are a total of ${120 \choose 3}$ ways to pick 3 books. There are ${24 \choose 3}$ ways to pick 3 distinct topics, and $5^3$ ways to pick from the books within those topics. Therefore, we get: $$\frac{{24 \choose 3} \cdot 5^3}{{120 \choose 3}}$$

**What is the probability of choosing "r" books such that at least one book is on a repeated topic?**

This calls for complementary counting. Let's find the number of ways to choose "r" books such that no books are of the same topic. Similar to above, we calculate a total of ${120 \choose r}$ ways to pick r books. There are ${24 \choose r}$ ways to pick r distinct topics, and $5^r$ ways to pick the books from said topics. We get: $$\frac{{24 \choose r} \cdot 5^r}{{120 \choose r}}$$

Since we're doing complementary counting, we have to subtract that probability from 1: $$1 - \frac{{24 \choose r} \cdot 5^r}{{120 \choose r}}$$

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hello Pradeep, just to let you know: (120C1 * (120-5)C1 * (120-5*2)C1 / 3!) does give the same answer as the one in my post (yay!). I see why it works, so good job!

Comment: I just verified that your and my solution are the same and felt very happy that I could solve such a problem after 18 years. I also had the complementary counting derivation in my own way (which matches the answer given by you) but didn't know how to format the equation in this forum

Comment: Formatting in done in LaTeX, which you can take a look at here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. :D

Comment: The probability of randomly choosing 5 books all from the same topic is:

(120 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)/120C5. 

Is this correct?

Comment: No, there might be repeats. There's 24 topics and exactly one way to pick all 5 books in that topic, so it should be 24 / 120C5 I guess. It's a very low chance!